# How the retrieve the equation of a trend line in a usable format

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I want to use the equation of a trend line in a formula in a cell and also in a C/C++ program. This is a recurring problem when analysing sensor data.

The method I am currently using is:

- Select and copy the formula
- Paste in LibreOffice Draw
- Right click and choose "Break"
- Select and copy the part that I need.
- Convert the text in the formula, for instance x² needs to be changed to "^2", and for C/C++ I need to convert it to "pow(x, 2)"
- 0.003 x² needs a multiplicator: 0.003*x^2
- A minus sign is some kind of horizontal line but NOT a minus sign
- Sometimes a space before the "=" needs to be trimmed

That's too many actions to do manually!

I really don't understand why Calc does not have an option to use the formula in Calc itself. How difficult is it to add "Copy formula" to the context menu?

My question:
How can I paste the formula in my own program instead of the Draw program?
I don't know what kind of clipboard format is used, it does not paste in any of my editors.

Once I have the contents of this unknown object I know how to process it any further in C++.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it would work to write a macro that does the following:

1. Read the formula from the chart.
2. Use regular expressions to make the necessary changes and put the result into a cell.
3. Use the dispatcher to select the contents of the cell and Copy.

Now your C++ program can Paste the string from the system clipboard.

There is a discussion about the system clipboard at https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=13783, where one user writes that simply copying and pasting is effective, instead of using the UNO clipboard API.

Basic might be the easiest language to write this macro in, although it is possible to write UNO components in C++ that can operate from within LibreOffice.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.Read the formula from the chart

There is the first problem.
When I copy the object from Calc and try to process the clipboard data in c++ with wxWidgets

```
void convertFrame::OnButton1Click( wxCommandEvent& event ) {
    if( wxTheClipboard->Open() ) {
        if( wxTheClipboard->IsSupported( wxDF_BITMAP ) ) {
            wxMessageBox( L"image" );
        }
    }
    wxTheClipboard->Close();
}
```

It tells me that the clipboard contains a bitmap image.
Would it really be an image, and the break function in Draw performs OCR?
I can't believe that!

EDIT:
I can also paste the contents of the clipboard, the formula, in Gimp.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to work with LibreOffice objects outside of LibreOffice, which doesn't make sense to me. The full context of my first point was "...write a macro that... [reads] the formula from the chart." A macro is simple (i.e. not a component / service) scripted code such as Basic or Python that is run from within LibreOffice. Or, if you want to write only in C++, you could set up a C++ UNO component to do the same thing but with tighter integration. That would require downloading the matching LibreOffice SDK version and linking to the libraries with `make`.

Comment: To answer the question in your answer, your C++ program really is getting a bitmap image, as is Gimp, because you're pasting it outside of LibreOffice. Whereas in Draw, the actual UNO object can be transferred. There might be some way of working with the object from outside as OLE (object linking and embedding), but that doesn't sound promising to me. If one were to do something like that, keep in mind that the clipboard can have multiple formats, so you would need to get the format you want, not the bitmap one.

Comment: I'm only using the front end from Calc. I agree that a macro is a better way than taking a D-tour through an external program but I know how to write C++, not Libre Office macros. When I read your answer, I missed the part about the UNO objects. I will investigate that and see if I can catch the 'UNO' from the clipboard and process that in C++, thanks.

Comment: "see if I can catch the 'UNO' from the clipboard" — like this UNO call, although it might only work that way from within LibreOffice: https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/interfacecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1datatransfer_1_1XTransferable.html#ab3ae2fe685248536213f2e98edeb3672